# Swift How to go Back to previous view controller when bar button tapped

Tags: swift, button, uinavigationbar, action, uibarbuttonitem

I'm new to Swift programming and here is a really simple question.
How can I go back to previous view controller when a bar button is tapped?
My view controllers are all tableviews, none are navigation controllers. I inserted a bar on top of my table view and added a bar button item and created an action outlet but don't know what code to put inside. I found some responses on stackoverflow that are using a popviewcontrollerAnimated but when I write popviewcontrollerAnimated it says unresolved identifier. I have four viewcontrollers atm, ViewController,SecondViewController,ThirdViewController and FourthViewController.

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: How did you show the view controller? Did you use `navigationController.pushViewController(viewController:animated:)`?

Comment: I created a segue by control clicking from back button to the previous view controller

Comment: You should have at least one UINavigationController, how are you currently moving from one view controller to the other?

Comment: Either way, you should use `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`. You get the compile error because `popViewController` is not a method of your view controller, but rather the `navigationController`.

Comment: You should embed your first `viewController` into a `navigationController`. You can do this in Xcode: Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller. If you have many `viewControllers`, I would recommend to use the `navigationController`. If you are concerned about the Navigation Bar showing on all `viewControllers`, you can disable it by clicking the newly created `navigationController` and in the Attributes Inspector, uncheck Show Navigation Bar. Once you do this, you can freely call the `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` method.